# Finding interval of increase and decrease of rational functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have a graph of 
$$y = \frac{x^2}{x^2 - 2} - \frac{1}{2}$$ 
I see that as $x$ approaches $\infty$, $y$ approaches $1/2$. However, when $x$ approaches $-\infty$, does $y$ approach $-1/2$ or $+1/2$?

I tried to use graphing calculators, such as Desmos, as well as Wolfram Alpha. However, I was not sure about the last part; does $y$ approach $-1/2$ or $+1/2$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Rational functions have a single horizontal asymptote.

Comment: $1/2$. Note that the graph of our function is symmetric about the $y$-axis.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to find the intervals of increasing and decreasing, as the title suggests? Or do you want to find the behavior as $x \to \pm \infty$, as your question's body suggests?

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \frac{x^2}{x^2 - 2} - \frac{1}{2}$$
$$y =1+ 2\frac{x^2}{x^2 - 2} - \frac{1}{2}$$
$$y = \frac{1}{x^2 - 2} + \frac{1}{2}$$

The asymptotes :

For $x=\pm\infty \quad \frac{1}{x^2 - 2}=0 \quad \implies \quad y=\frac{1}{2}\quad$ which is an horizontal asymptote.

For $x=-\sqrt{2} \quad (x^2-2)=0 \quad \frac{1}{x^2 - 2}=\pm\infty \quad \implies \quad y=\pm\infty\quad$ Hense $x=-\sqrt{2}$ is a vertical asymptote.

For $x=\sqrt{2} \quad (x^2-2)=0 \quad \frac{1}{x^2 - 2}=\pm\infty \quad \implies \quad y=\pm\infty\quad$ Hense $x=\sqrt{2}$ is a vertical asymptote.

The variation of $y$ as a function on $x$ :

$(x^2-2)$ is an increassing function. Hense $\frac{1}{x^2 - 2}$ is a decreassing function and then $y(x)$ is a drecreassing function.

Starting from $(x=-\infty\:,\:y=\frac{1}{2})$ while $x$ increasses up to $-\sqrt{2}\quad$ $y$ decreasses to $-\infty$.

Then starting from $(x>-\sqrt{2}\:,\:y=+\infty) \quad$ while $x$ increasses up to $+\sqrt{2}\quad$ $y$ decreasses to $-\infty$.

Then starting from $(x>+\sqrt{2}\:,\:y=+\infty) \quad$ while $x$ increasses up to $+\infty\quad$ $y$ decreasses to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try thinking about this intuitively.
Just plug in some values...
$$\frac{1,000,000,000^2}{1,000,000,000^2-2}-\frac{1}{2}$$
and compare that with
$$\frac{(-1,000,000,000)^2}{(-1,000,000,000)^2-2}-\frac{1}{2}$$

You don't need calculus for this particular problem; you need (what teachers call) "number sense".